# How to create datatype jsonblob?

Tags: json, sqlite

Table:

| id | filejson |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | data1.json |
| 2 | data2.json |

Or:

| ID | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | data1 |
| 3 | data2 |

Also how to query data in data.json? Is there any alternative way of storing JSON data in SQLite?

Comment: See how to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started. More details can be found in [https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#:~:text=SQLite%20stores%20JSON%20as%20ordinary,a%20binary%20encoding%20of%20JSON](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#:%7E:text=SQLite%20stores%20JSON%20as%20ordinary,a%20binary%20encoding%20of%20JSON).

```
create table json_example (
    id      int primary key,
    json    text);
    
insert into json_example
values
(1, '{"name": "jason", "gender": "m"}'),
(2, '{"name": "catherine", "gender": "f"}');

select id,
       json,
       json_extract(json,'$.name') as name,
       json_extract(json,'$.gender') as gender
  from json_example;
```

```
id|json                                |name     |gender|
--+------------------------------------+---------+------+
 1|{"name": "jason", "gender": "m"}    |jason    |m     |
 2|{"name": "catherine", "gender": "f"}|catherine|f     |
```